# “Installing for X86_64_efi platform” system freezes

Tags: screen, freeze

I am trying to install ubuntu as dual boot in Aspire ES 15..Es1-533-p21L..When installer reaches “Installing for X86_64_efi platform” system hangs or screen freezes. When I checked in bios UEFI is enabled in boot..Please help to fix this problem